# Use PayPal sdk in Android Eclipse project

Tags: android, eclipse, paypal

I would like to use PayPal sdk in my Android app. My app is developed as Eclipse project.

I don't know why PayPal has only the sdk in aar format.
This is the link:
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK

I would like a jar file. How can I use this aar file?

Comment: Uninstall Eclipse. Install Android Studio. Now go and enjoy your new and improved dependency manager.

Comment: They shouldn't have to ask you. You should post your answer and then accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution.
To run PayPal SDK 2.13.1 on Eclipse project you need 3 jars:

- PayPalAndroidSDK-2.13.1.jar
- okhttp-3.0.1.jar
- okio-1.6.0.jar

Follow this link to download a zip with these 3 jars. Unpack it and put the jars in libs folder.

http://www.antonioviolaux.com/paypal-2.13.1-eclipse/paypal-2.13.1-eclipse.zip

Do not forget manifest configuration as PayPal example project.

If this is helpful, please rate me.

Comment: It's only showing to pay with Paypal, how to give Card option in Payment? can you tell me.